# How can I control specific traffic like UDP traffic with iptables on ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, bash, firewall, iptables

If for example I would like to send just the UDP traffic to an IP-address,
is it possible to do this with iptables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 2.2.2.2 -i eth0 -p udp -j ACCEPT
```

-A --append = Will add one or more rules to the end of the selected chain

FORWARD = will forward the traffic

-d = Destination IP

-i = Interface

-p udp = Protocol for udp

-j = Specifies the target of the rule

Hope this helps!